# В этом коде есть ошибка, не могу понять из-за чего

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package blinmaker;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class cooker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int eggsAmount;
    int eggsMin = 1;
    int milkAmount;
    int milkMin = 200; //milliliter
    int flourAmount;
    int flourMin = 100; //grams

    System.out.println ("Hello, Nastya!");
    System.out.println("Blinmaker is starting up...");
    System.out.println("How many eggs you have?");

    Scanner userInput;
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    eggsAmount = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have " + eggsAmount + " eggs");
    //eggs done

    System.out.println("How much milk you have?");
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    milkAmount = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have " + milkAmount + "ml milk");
    //milk done

    System.out.println("How much flour you have?");
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    flourAmount = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have " + flourAmount + "g flour");

    //main code here
    if (eggsAmount < eggsMin || milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount < flourMin);
    System.out.println("No blin today");

    } else { 
        //calculation
        flourAmount = flourAmount / flourMin;
        System.out.println("You have " + flourAmount + " portions of flour");

        milkAmount = milkAmount / milkMin;
        System.out.println("You have " + " portions of milk");

        //find smallest number of all 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте `{` вместо `;` в конце этой строки:

```
if (eggsAmount < eggsMin || milkAmount < milkMin || flourAmount < flourMin);
```

Comment: Благодарю вас мисье

Comment: @Hacker'smom Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.